# How can you only extract 30 seconds of audio using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg for audio conversion. I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 file.wav
```

This works fine. However I only want to my output file to contain maximum 1 minute of audio. How can I do that using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 30 -i file.mp3 file.wav
```

- `-ss 0` - Start at 0 seconds
- `-t 30` - Capture 30 seconds (from 0, so 0:00 - 0:30). If you want 1 minute of audio, use `-t 60`.
- `file.mp3` - Input file
- `file.wav` - output file

Comment: `-t` is actually an output option. The format should be `ffmpeg -ss 0 -i file.mp3 -t 30 file.wav`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without re-encoding? I wrote `ffmpeg -ss 0 -i in.m4a -t 240 out.m4a` and got 128kbps output from 253kbps input. EDIT: I found it, just add `-acodec copy`.

Answer (score 20):

This command also works perfect. I cropped my music from 0 seconds to 30 seconds.
Here **test.mp3** is **input file** and **temp.mp3** is **output file**.

> -ss: Indicates the starting point.
>
> -to: Indicates where to stop.
>
> -y : force output file to overwrite.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -c copy -y temp.mp3
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the  `-t` parameter:

> -t **duration**
>             Restrict the transcoded/captured video sequence to the duration specified in seconds.
>              "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" syntax is also supported.