# Batch extract first 10 seconds of multiple mp3 files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder filled with songs. I would like to make ONE mp3 file containing a mashup of 10 seconds of each song.

I have found that FFMPEG is an easy software to do so.

I found [how to cut a single file :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945747/how-can-you-only-extract-30-seconds-of-audio-using-ffmpeg) `ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 10 -i file.mp3 file.wav`

And [how to write a loop for multiple steps :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921316/batch-extracting-frames-from-multiple-mp4-file) `for i in *.mp3; do ...`

But I am not sure how to mix the two into only 1 file. If it's not possible, I guess I can also make a separate 10 sec file for each and then regroup.

Comment: I think your suggestion at the end is easy and straightforward.  1. Create the 10 seconds clips for each file 2. Join them.

Answer (score 0):

**In Windows**

Step 1 : Go into the folder with the songs

Step 2 : Paste the following line

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b *.mp3') DO ffmpeg -ss 15 -t 10 -i "%G" -acodec mp3 "%~nG_10s.mp3"
```

Step 3 : Put the 10s songs into another folder (or modify the regex) and paste

```
copy /b *.mp3 E:\combined.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the intermediate files by using ffmpeg's concat demuxer

**#1** Create the concat text file

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b *.mp3') DO (echo file '%G' >> list.txt & echo inpoint X >> list.txt & echo outpoint Y >> list.txt)
```

X and Y are the start and end times, in seconds.

**#2** Combine the selected portions

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -vn out.mp3
```