# How to extract 1st second of every wav file?

Tags: audio

I have over 1000 wav files and I want to extract 1st second of every audio file and save them in my machine locally.

Is there any software or code library which help me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have a skim over [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some advice on improving the question. You may want to state a particular programming language you are happy by adding the relevant tag. There is not a requirement to provide code in your question, but you may find you get a better response by attempting a solution first and providing what you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you only extract 30 seconds of audio using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945747/how-can-you-only-extract-30-seconds-of-audio-using-ffmpeg)